# How to converting format json in react JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert JSON format in JavaScript like this:

```
{
    "a": [5,1,2],
    "b": [4,0,3],
    "c": [1,1,4] 
}
```

to

```
[
    {'a':5,'b':4,'c':1},
    {'a':1,'b':0,'c':1},
    {'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}
]
```

How to solve this?

Comment: can you share what have you tried ?

Comment: Please see the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. What have you tried and do you have code? Read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
const obj = {
  "a": [5,1,2],
  "b": [4,0,3],
  "c": [1,1,4] 
};

const convert = (obj) => {
  let res = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  if (!keys.length) return [];
  for (let i = 0; i < obj[keys[0]].length; i++) {
    let nextObj = {};
    keys.forEach(key => {
      nextObj[key] = obj[key][i];
    });
    res.push(nextObj);
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(convert(obj))
```

Comment: No problem @user3440030 :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

```js
let obj = {
"a": [5,1,2],
"b": [4,0,3],
"c": [1,1,4] 
}

let result = [], idx=0;
while(true){
    let isValid = true, tempObj = {};
    for(element in obj){
        if(idx < obj[element].length){
            tempObj[element] = obj[element][idx];
        }
        else{
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    if(isValid){
        result.push(tempObj);
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
    idx++;
}

console.log(result);
```